# Was Karna put on stake in the game of dice?

Tags: mahabharata

In the Mahabharat serial shown on hotstar, it is shown that Karna was put on stake in the game of dice by Duryodhan and Arjun was put on stake by Yudhistira in front of him.

Is it actually true ? Was Karna actually put on stake ?

I am asking this as it is difficult for me [to accept this,](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02064.htm) as Karna was mere a friend of Duryodhan. A person has no right or authority over his friend. It is not possible to put a friend at stake.